# R markdown ioslides presentation layout

Tags: r, layout, markdown, presentation, ioslides

I am working on a presentation using R Markdown and ioslides
and I wonder what is the most complete way of controlling the 
layout of a particular slide or set of slides.

I already tried things like:

`## Title {.columns-2 .smaller}`

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

`<p class="forceBreak"></p>`

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

but I need a more general way of controlling the layout
including the position and margins of figures, text, titles 
and R plots.

After a long search, I couldn't find the information I need.

Could you suggest me a reference or a link?

Comment: Not answering your question but I suggest you take a look at [xaringan](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#1) ([link](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/)). Much easier to customize slides imo

Comment: Examples: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/pull/113 & https://www.jvcasillas.com/midd_xaringan/slides/index.html#1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Juan